# How to find a ring with a given automorphism group

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, automorphism-group

I'm hoping to find an example of a ring whose automorphism group is D8, i.e. the order 8 dihedral group. This raises the question of how, given a group $G$ to find a ring $R$ whose automorphism group is $G$?

Any ideas on how to approach this problem in general or for the specific example would be appreciated.

So far I can see that the automorphism group of $\bf{Z} \times ... \times \bf{Z}$ $n$-times is $S_n$. Also I noticed that the group ring ${\bf Z}G$ contains $G$ in its automorphism group, but it is often larger.

Comment: One “easy” way would be to find $G$ as a Galois group over the rationals.

Comment: What action of $G$ on $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ do you have in mind? Left multiplication isn't a ring action and conjugation isn't faithful (its kernel is the center). As TokenToucan says, in this special case you can try to exhibit $G$ as a Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$, which turns out to not be so bad (try $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$).

Comment: I had conjugation in mind, as you say I'm looking for ring automorphisms. I don't see the problem with it being unfaithful?

Comment: The automorphism group of a ring acts faithfully on it by definition...

Comment: Oh I see, yeah good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Shafarevich's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#Partial_results) every finite solvable group (including $D_8$) is the automorphism group of some Galois extension of the field of rational numbers. See also this paper: K. Hashimoto & K. Miyake, Inverse Galois problem for dihedral groups,
Developments in Mathematics 2, Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1999, 165–
181. Or [this paper](http://www.math.ttu.edu/%7Ealedet/papers/dihedral.pdf), page 3. Or this [book](http://library.msri.org/books/Book45/files/book45.pdf), table on p.11.

Answer (score 1):

In this special case you can in fact take $R$ to be a number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$, the splitting field of $x^4 - 2$, so $D_8$ is its Galois group; this is a nice exercise. It's a famous open problem, the [inverse Galois problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem) over $\mathbb{Q}$, whether every finite group occurs as the Galois group of a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in this way.

In general the case of infinite groups seems hard but I think the case of finite groups is doable. The strategy I have in mind is to mimic the construction in [this math.SE answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168708/every-group-as-full-symmetry-group-of-points-in-mathbb-rd/1168756#1168756): given a finite group $G$ pick some action of it on an affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ (say coming from a faithful linear representation with no trivial components) over $\mathbb{Q}$, then find a subvariety $V \subsetneq \mathbb{A}^n$ which admits no nontrivial automorphisms. Then we can hope that the subvariety of all translates $gV, g \in G$ should have automorphism group exactly $G$, and take $R$ to be its ring of functions.